# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens - 2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy avanzando un pequeño proyecto y me topé con el siguiente mensaje al trata de ingresar data a mi base de datos.

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   C:\wamp64\www\craft\inventario\create.php on line 94

analicé mi código y no ubico el problema.

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO entradas SET 
        categoria_id = :categoria, 
        subcategoria_id = :subCategoria, 
        fabricante_id = :fabricante, 
        serial_number = :serialNumber, 
        modelo =: modelo,
        descripcion = :descripcion, 
        referencia_entrada_id = :referenciaEntrada, 
        fecha_ingreso = :fechaIngreso, 
        proveedor_id = :proveedor, 
        precio = :precio, 
        comprobante_id = :comprobante,
        numero_comprobante = :numeroComprobante, 
        moneda_id = :moneda, 
        tipo_de_cambio = :tipoCambio, 
        monto_total = :montoTotal, 
        comentario = :comentario";

        // prepare query for execution
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);


        // posted values
        $categoria_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['categoria']));
        $subcategoria_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['subCategoria']));
        $fabricante_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['fabricante']));
        $serial_number=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['serialNumber']));
        $modelo=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['modelo']));
        $descripcion=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['descripcion']));
        $referencia_entrada_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['referenciaEntrada']));
        $fecha_ingreso=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['fechaIngreso']));
        $proveedor_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['proveedor']));
        $precio=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['precio']));
        $comprobante_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['comprobante']));
        $numero_comprobante=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['numeroComprobante']));
        $moneda_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['moneda']));
        $tipo_de_cambio=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['tipoCambio']));
        $monto_total=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['montoTotal']));
        $comentario=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['comentario']));


        // bind the parameters
        $stmt->bindParam(':categoria', $categoria_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':subCategoria', $subcategoria_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fabricante', $fabricante_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':serialNumber', $serial_number);
        $stmt->bindParam(':modelo', $modelo);
        $stmt->bindParam(':descripcion', $descripcion);
        $stmt->bindParam(':referenciaEntrada', $referencia_entrada_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fechaIngreso', $fecha_ingreso);
        $stmt->bindParam(':proveedor', $proveedor_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':precio', $precio);
        $stmt->bindParam(':comprobante', $comprobante_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':numeroComprobante', $numero_comprobante);
        $stmt->bindParam(':moneda', $moneda_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tipoCambio', $tipo_de_cambio);
        $stmt->bindParam(':montoTotal', $monto_total);
        $stmt->bindParam(':comentario', $comentario);
```

Las columnas de mi BD son:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían darme un mano por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando usas consultas preparadas no necesitas aplicar `htmlspecialchars` ni `strip_tags` a los datos, pues las consultas preparadas se encargan de determinar si hay algo tramposo en cualquier dato. No sé si la aplicación de esas funciones estén creando un dato confuso o algo así. Recomiendo que crees las variables sin aplicar ambas funciones, prueba y dinos si sigue el mismo error.